# How to correctly generate training data based on percentages?

Tags: python, pandas, probability, bayesian, training-data

I have a question.

I am currently generating training data for my bayesian network as follows:
(also as code down below)

[image: picture of data]

-> infected stands for people who are infected (0= not infected, 1= infected)
-> p_tests is the result of the test (0= test negative, 1= test positive)

Wether there is a 0 or 1 in TP, FN, FP and TN is decided like this:

```
data = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 2))
columns = ['infected', 'p_tests']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df["TP"] = ((df['infected'] == 1) & (df['p_tests'] == 1)).astype(int)
df["FN"] = ((df['infected'] == 1) & (df['p_tests'] == 0)).astype(int)
df["FP"] = ((df['infected'] == 0) & (df['p_tests'] == 1)).astype(int)
df["TN"] = ((df['infected'] == 0) & (df['p_tests'] == 0)).astype(int)

print(df)
```

So that is running fine.

My question now would be, how I can decide eg. the 1 and 0 of the infected group based on my probabilities.

The chance to be infected is 10%. How can I program the data, so that 10% of my set have 1s (show that 10% are infected) ?

The same is with the probability of TP (80%), TN(98%), FP(2%), FN(20%)

Does anyone have an Ideo on how to solve this?

Comment: please provide your input data as text or DataFrame constructor, **not image**

Comment: edited now. Is it better like this?

Comment: do you mean you want the random infected to have 10% of 1s? Try `np.random.choice` with a defined probability

Comment: TP, TN, FP and FN are calculated values; you should set `infected` and `p_tests` at random (based on the desired probabilities), and compute the other columns as you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign values at random with a set probability, e.g. *P(infected) = 0.9*, you can proceed like this:

1. Choose random floating-point values `r` in the range `(0, 1.0)`

   ```
    df['r'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1.0, size=df.shape[0])
   ```
2. Set the value of `infected` based on the probability threshold:

   ```
    df['infected'] = (df['r'] >= 0.9).astype(int)
   ```

Comment: -> Choose random floating-point values r in the range (0, 1.0) <- And how do I do that? I couldnt work it out like this: r = np.random.uniform(0, 1.0)

Comment: Added it to the answer. You need a column of random values of the same size.